# mark file as active - eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, file, eclipse-plugin

i wrote a plugin for a eclipse that let user creating my own type of project , the template of the project have some configuration files and I want to give the user the option to chose which one will be active, it's mean which one i will use when i will compile the project, i add an action of this files that let the user set it as active, my question is if there is any way to mark it in the package explorer(maybe bold ar with some border) as active so when user look at this he can know which one is the active now

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the decorator extension point `org.eclipse.ui.decorators`. Add this to your plugin.xml:

```xml
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.decorators">
   <decorator
         adaptable="true"
         class="MyDecoratorClass"
         id="some.id.for.decorator"
         label="Active Build Configuration Decorator"
         lightweight="true"
         location="BOTTOM_RIGHT"
         state="false">
      <enablement>
         <and>
            <objectClass
                  name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
            </objectClass>
            <or>
               <objectClass
                     name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
               </objectClass>
               <objectClass
                     name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
               </objectClass>
            </or>
         </and>
      </enablement>
   </decorator>
</extension>
```

Provide implementation in your `MyDecoratorClass` (or whatever name you choose) to check your project's active config and either adding text, or images. Perhaps have something like this:  []

Whenever a user makes a modification that requires you to update the decorators so that the latest changes can be decorated you can use this:

```java
// the resource whose properties changed and needs to be re-decorated
IResource resource = ...;

IDecoratorManager manager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager();
IBaseLabelProvider decorator = manager.getBaseLabelProvider("id.of.my.decorator");
if (decorator != null)
    ((ILabelProviderListener) manager).labelProviderChanged(new LabelProviderChangedEvent(decorator, resource));
```

Comment: thanks , what do you mean when you say like this[], can you please give me more information how to implement this class?

Comment: I still need some help please if I add the folowing implementaion public String decorateText(String text, Object element) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"+text;
 }when this function is call?

Comment: ok, i got it , but how how can  add the decorator only when user choose the file to be active?i want it to be something dynamic that when ever user choose a file to be active the decorator will be added and will be removed from the other files

Comment: @user758795 I have updated the answer with info on how to refresh the decorators when properties for a file change.

Comment: thanks, i can't see which function when call when firing labelProviderChanged event

Comment: i had another problem : i get null for   IBaseLabelProvider decorator = manager.getBaseLabelProvider("some.id.for.decorator"); when i have in the plugin.xml for the decorator   id="some.id.for.decorator"

Comment: Can you try suffixing your plugin ID as well like this: <plugin_id>.<decorator_id>. Is the rest of your decorator working? Maybe you didn't set it up correctly. Make sure first that it works, then you should be able to fetch it using this code.